# What is this file $WINRE_BACKUP_PARTITION.MARKER

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a hidden file on my C: drive named `$WINRE_BACKUP_PARTITION.MARKER`, of size 0. I don't know when it appeared there and couldn't find any relevant information about it online.

Does anyone know what it does, and if it's safe to delete?

Answer (score 9):

This *file* also exists on machines that have not failed any update process. It has nothing to do with updates, though it may appear after an update as a consequence of attempting operations on an absent recovery partition (a better guess than the one above).

I have seen this on a variety of machines, all of which had Windows 10 installed as a single partition with no recovery. Deleting it has never caused issues with normal use.

Answer (score 4):

This folder will be created when the Feature upgrade failed or have some failed history.

I have checked my computers which has successfully upgraded to new Version of Windows and another has failed on this, this folder will be created on the failed one.

[image]